# find(:all) and then add data from another table to the object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, object, response

I have two tables:

```
create_table "friendships", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user1_id"
    t.integer  "user2_id"
    t.boolean  "hasaccepted"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

and

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.boolean  "gender"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.date     "birthday"
end
```

I need to show the user a list of `Friendrequests`, so I use this method in my controller:

```
def getfriendrequests
    respond_to do |format|
        case params[:id]
            when "to_me"
                @friendrequests = Friendship.find(:all, :conditions => { :user2_id => session[:user], :hasaccepted => false })
            when "from_me"
                @friendrequests = Friendship.find(:all, :conditions => { :user1_id => session[:user], :hasaccepted => false })
        end
        format.xml  { render :xml  => @friendrequests }
        format.json { render :json => @friendrequests }
    end
end
```

I do nearly everything using AJAX, so to fetch the First and Last name of the user with UID `user2_id` (the `to_me` param comes later, don't worry right now), I need a for loop which make multiple AJAX calls. This sucks and costs much bandwidth. So I'd rather like that `getfriendrequests` also returns the First and Last name of the corresponding users, so, e.g. the JSON response would not be:

```
[
  {
    "friendship": {
      "created_at": "2010-02-19T13:51:31Z",
      "user1_id": 2,
      "updated_at": "2010-02-19T13:51:31Z",
      "hasaccepted": false,
      "id": 11,
      "user2_id": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "friendship": {
      "created_at": "2010-02-19T16:31:23Z",
      "user1_id": 2,
      "updated_at": "2010-02-19T16:31:23Z",
      "hasaccepted": false,
      "id": 12,
      "user2_id": 4
    }
  }
]
```

but rather:

```
[
  {
    "friendship": {
      "created_at": "2010-02-19T13:51:31Z",
      "user1_id": 2,
      "updated_at": "2010-02-19T13:51:31Z",
      "hasaccepted": false,
      "id": 11,
      "user2_id": 3,
      "firstname": "Jon",
      "lastname": "Skeet"
    }
  },
  {
    "friendship": {
      "created_at": "2010-02-19T16:31:23Z",
      "user1_id": 2,
      "updated_at": "2010-02-19T16:31:23Z",
      "hasaccepted": false,
      "id": 12,
      "user2_id": 4,
      "firstname": "Mark",
      "lastname": "Gravell"
    }
  }
]
```

I thought of a for loop in the `getfriendrequests` method, but I don't know how to implement this, and maybe there is an easier way. It must also work for XML. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
render :xml  => @friendrequests
```

Rails iterates each element in the array and calls the `ActiveRecord::Base#to_xml` method. 
Likewise, the `:json` option means a call to `ActiveRecord::Base#to_json`.

Both [to_xml](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/XmlSerialization.html) and [to_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001873) have a `:methods` option which contains an array of methods to include in the serialization.

The solution is really straightforward. Override these methods.

```
class Friendship

  # ...

  def firstname
    # here get the first name
  end

  def lastname
    # here get the last name
  end

  def to_xml(options = {})
    options[:methods] ||= [:firstname, :lastname]
    super(options)
  end

  def to_json(options = {})
    options[:methods] ||= [:firstname, :lastname]
    super(options)
  end

end
```

Comment: Cool, but how do I make sure Rails only does this for getfriendrequests and not for other methods?

Comment: You could write something like `to_json_with_names` that could wrap what Simone has described above.

Comment: You should also add `:include => :userX` to the join table to cut down on DB queries. Where :userX is the association on FriendshipRequest that corresponds to the other user in the table (not current user)